# Fabricjs History Undo/Redo on Multiple Canvases

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

So I have multiple canvases stored in array where I manipulate with `fabricjs-history` Undo/Redo and it works pretty well.

The challenge I have is that, because I have multiple canvases in a page, when canvas B is deleted, I use `canvas.dispose()` and then delete that element tag but don't have any idea how to Undo a deleted canvas which consist of multiple objects as the deleted canvas isn't stored in `fabricjs-history`

Any idea or suggestion would be helpful